# Is there a way to compare two fields in a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a collection called game that has a schema like this.

```
{"team": "A", "opponent": "B", "points": 101, "opp_points": 100}
{"team": "B", "opponent": "A", "points": 100, "opp_points": 101}
```

Is there a way to query on a comparison between two fields in the same collection?

The SQL equivalent would be.

```
SELECT * FROM game where points > opp_points;
```

I have looked through Mongo's documentation and haven't found this, but thought they probably have it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$expr` in `$match` in aggregation or in `$find`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$points",
          "$opp_points"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0-lr8jjn62-) of aggregation**

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      "$points",
      "$opp_points"
    ]
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hFdkZcOfAND) of find**